# How to pass parameters for output in C++

Tags: c++, output-parameter

Some of methods that I see in C++ code are of this structure:

```
void Class::method1(int &a);
```

and are called like this:

```
int a;
class->method1(a);
```

But sometimes I see structures like:

```
void Class2::method2(int* a);
```

And these methods are called like this:

```
int a;
class2->method2(&a);
```

I understand that in the first case the method accepts an address of a variable, and in the second - pointer to a variable, right?

Could someone explain to me what is the difference between these two approaches, and when to use which?

Also, in the first example, it seems that a method can be taking "int& a" or "int a", and in both cases we would call it the same way: int a; class->method1(a); ? This seems confusing.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to give you something to think about. What do you think could "int*&" or "int**" mean? Whats the difference and where could this be useful.

Comment: in the second case `class2->method2(NULL);` is acceptable. That's the main difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
void Class::method1(int &a);
```

This is passing by reference.

```
void Class2::method2(int* a);
```

This is passing the pointer. In `class2->method2(&a);`, `&` is the address of operater.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the method accept a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29) to the variable.
It means that if a is modified inside the `method1`, it will be modified after the function returns.

In the second case, it accepts a [pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29) to the variable. A pointer is the memory adress of the variable. It's what the `&` retrieves : The address (aka a pointer to a).

Both type have essentially the same purpose : Being able to modify a variable of a different scope.

See that example :

```
void fooPointer (int* pointer) {
    *pointer += 1;
}

void fooReference (int& reference) {
    reference += 1;
}

int main () {
    int a = 0;

    std::cout << a; // Ouputs 0

    fooPointer (&a);
    std::cout << a; // Outputs 1

    fooReference (a);
    std::cout << a; // Outputs 2
}
```

As you can see, both allow you to do the same here. But using references is usually easier and more readable, because everything is done implicitly, so you don't have to `reference` (`*`) or `dereference` (`&`) your variables.

Comment: So would the a be modified at a different time in the second case?

Answer (score 0):

First one is called using a reference to a variable, second one - using a pointer. There are some difference between the two concepts. I encourage you to google this, but the most important ones I can think of right now are that a reference can not be constructed without pointing to an existing object and that a pointer can be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

`void Class::method1(int &a)` means you are passing `a` by reference and the caller can expect `a` to be modified.

`void Class2::method2(int* a)` means you are passing `a` by pointer and the caller can expect the thing to which `a` points to be modified.

Personally I don't like pass by reference since the caller doesn't quickly know if `a` will be modified as the calling syntax for pass by reference and pass by value are identical. Passing by *constant reference* `void Class::method1(const int &a)` is better still since then `a` cannot be modified and you can gain an efficiency in not taking value copies if `a` is a large object.

However many folk differ in their opinion and say that you should pass by pointer if the function allows the pointer to be null; i.e. can your function do something useful without `a` inputted?